# strange behaviour of camel wildfly/undertow integration on jboss eap fuse 7 - it's bug or i'm making a wrong usage?

Tags: apache-camel, wildfly, jbossfuse, undertow, cxfrs

i'm facing a strange bug in camel integration with jboss eap undertow subsystem.

I'm deploying in jboss eap 7 with fuse patch 7.0.0 several wars each exposing jaxrs endpoints realized as routes with cxf consumers.

I've realized a poc available here:

https://github.com/bassista/jboss_fuse_camel_cxf_undertow_bug

to reproduce the issue.

Here is the issue:

Each web app that contains a route with a cxf consumer defines an implicit web context on Undertow, but when a web app is undeployed, say app1, the wrong context is removed from Undertow, say the web context of app2, thus you can't reach the routes of both apps.

I think it's a bug, but it's so evident that it is strange it never popped up before. The WildFly-Camel Subsystem isn't a fresh project and I can't find any related issue to this one. I'm wrong in something or this is actually a bug? Do you have any workaround to suggest? At the moment i'm forced to reboot the server after each deploy/replace/undeploy.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who stumbles across this problem, it seems there was a race condition in Fuse  EAP 7.0. The problem is fixed in versions greater or equal to Fuse 7.1.

There's some more information in the WildFly-Camel GitHub project issue here:

https://github.com/wildfly-extras/wildfly-camel/issues/2679